# MySQL - Can I combine many queries on the same table into 1 query?

Tags: mysql

I have many queries, can I combine it into 1 to optimize?

1. `SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory <= 5 AND cat_id = 1`
2. `SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory BETWEEN 5 AND 10 AND cat_id = 1`
3. `SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory > 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you.  It will return the 3 counts in a single SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN inventory <= 5 AND cat_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Q1Result,
   SUM(CASE WHEN inventory BETWEEN 5 AND 10 AND cat_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Q2Result,
   SUM(CASE WHEN  inventory > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Q3Result
FROM products
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b78/3).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory <= 5 AND cat_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory BETWEEN 5 AND 10 AND cat_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory > 10
```

You'll get back multiple rows from the queries all in one big long list.

Comment: Sure you don't want to use `UNION ALL`? You also need to alias the column in the first statement.

Comment: UNION ALL would work as well. It would probably be faster too -- as long as he can be sure all the data id DISTINCT already (unless that doesn't matter to him.)

Comment: I would recommend changing your answer to use `UNION ALL` because 1) it is faster 2) it will assure that OP has a result from each query if they are not `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
select sum( x ) from query 1 union query 2  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b78/4)

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory <= 5 AND cat_id = 1
    ) AS count1,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory BETWEEN 5 AND 10 AND cat_id = 1
    ) AS count2,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(prod_id) FROM products WHERE inventory > 10
    ) AS count3
```

Comment: I was doing it this way, but it's 3 subqueries, and there has to be a way to put it into 1 query. But thank you for answering. The SQL Fiddle is really cool!!